# Generate regular pattern in std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

I am looking for a resource effective method to set the bits at specific positions in a std_logic_vector.

Let's assume that I have a std_logic_vector such as `signal a := std_logic_vector(LEN-1 downto 0) := (others => '0')`,
where LEN is a generic.
I want to set it to `1` at regular intervalls, e.g., at the fifth, tenth, ... position, where the intervall might come from a (small) set of predefined numbers,
e.g., `(5,10,20,25,30,40,50)`.
What is the most resource-saving method to accomplish this?

Obviously this can be achieved using a `for` loop and the `mod` function.
However, I want to use this method for synthesis, so the mod function might be to expensive. Another possibility would be to unroll the loop.. however, since `LEN` is a generic, I do not know the number of steps. Furthermore, I would like to exclude impossible combinations, e.g., if `LEN = 20`, the invervalls `> 20` should be excluded.

Comment: You're doing the mod between a restricted set of predefined numbers and a bit position; both of those are constant. The most expensive part is likely to be decoding your input selection if you don't make it one hot.

Comment: You could write a function to produce a value for  one or more  constant declarations.  Because you synthesize an elaborated design that provides no cost other than whatever mechanism you use to consume the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yann's answer has a few issues that I'd like to address here to provide an answer for those less versed in VHDL syntax.  This isn't a critique of the implementation Yann chose, but rather to clarify syntax issues.

First, the above example is not complete.  It describes a `component` statement, but no corresponding `entity`.  The use of `component` is only in declarative regions, and cannot exist standalone outside of a `package` or `architecture`.  As written, it will not compile.  Rather, it should be changed to:

```
entity columns is
...
end entity columns;
```

Second, one cannot declare arrays without a corresponding type declaration.  That is, the example in Yann's post:

```
values  : array (0 to choices-1) of integer
```

cannot be done.  A type must be declared before it can be used.  And in order to have that type visible to the component/entity, it must be defined prior to the `component` or `entity`.  In the case of an `entity`, it needs to be defined in a package.  For example:

```
package columns_pkg is
  type values_array is array(natural range <>) of integer;
end package columns_pkg;
```

Then `columns_pkg` can be referenced in the `entity`.  Such as:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.columns_pkg.all;

entity columns is
  generic (
    LEN     : integer;                  -- bits of output
    choices : integer;                  -- number of column combinations
      -- distances at which bits may be 1
    values  : values_array(0 to choices-1)
  );
  ...
```

Now, this still isn't quite right.  Only in VHDL-2008 can generics be dependent upon each other.  That is, the range of `values` can only be dependent upon `choices` in VHDL-2008.  Earlier language versions require them to be unrelated, which means the declaration of `values` above will fail in VHDL-2002 and earlier.

But it turns out that `choices` isn't even necessary.  Rather, one can do this (bringing it all together and cleaning up a couple of typos):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package columns_pkg is
  type values_array is array(natural range <>) of integer;
end package columns_pkg;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.columns_pkg.all;

entity columns is
  generic
  (
    LEN     : integer;                  -- bits of output
    values  : values_array
  );
  port
  (
    -- one hot encoded distance choice
    distance : in  std_logic_vector(values'length-1 downto 0);
    -- data which is 1 at selected distance
    bits     : out std_logic_vector(LEN-1 downto 0)
  );
end entity columns;

architecture behavioural of columns is    
begin  -- architecture behavioural

  bitgen: for i in bits'range generate
  begin
    -- purpose: calculate one individual bit
    -- type   : combinational
    -- inputs : distance
    -- outputs: bits(i)
    bitcalc: process (distance) is
      variable j : integer;
    begin  -- process bitcalc
      bits(i) <= '0';
      for j in values'range loop
        if i mod values(j) = 0 and distance(j) = '1' then
          bits(i) <= '1';
        end if;
      end loop;  -- j
    end process bitcalc;
  end generate;

end architecture behavioural;
```

Note that `values` is unconstrained.  The length will be determined at elaboration time.  And one can make use of attributes to determine the length and range.

Also, if there is a relationship between `LEN` and the range of `values`, then the `LEN` generic can also probably be eliminated.

And finally, to make use of `columns`, one does:

```
entity top is
end entity top;

use work.columns_pkg.all;

architecture behavioural of top is
  constant columns_values : values_array(0 to 5) := (0, 5, 10, 15);

  -- one hot encoded distance choice
  signal distance : std_logic_vector(columns_values'length-1 downto 0);

  -- data which is 1 at selected distance
  signal bits     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
  columns_inst : entity work.columns
  generic map
  (
    LEN => bits'length,
    values => columns_values
  )
  port map
  (
    distance => distance,
    bits => bits
  );

end architecture behavioural;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your numbers are predefined, you're only doing modulo between a constant bit position and one (of a handful) constant number. This can be done with a set of two loops that produce a simple and/or tree per bit. It's fairly likely the synthesizer can eliminate some common logic as well. I'd likely encode the step distance as one hot, or perhaps a tree form such that 5 implies n*5 as well. I guess the code might resemble:

```
component columns is
  generic (
    LEN     : integer;                  -- bits of output
    choices : integer;                  -- number of column combinations
      -- distances at which bits may be 1
    values  : array (0 to choices-1) of integer);
  port (
      -- one hot encoded distance choice
    distance : in  std_logic_vector(choices-1 downto 0);
      -- data which is 1 at selected distance
    bits     : out std_logic_vector(LEN-1 downto 0));
end component columns;

architecture behavioural of columns is

begin  -- architecture behavioural

  bitgen: for i in 0 to choices-1 generate
  begin
    -- purpose: calculate one individual bit
    -- type   : combinational
    -- inputs : distance
    -- outputs: bits(i)
    bitcalc: process (distance) is
      variable j : integer;
    begin  -- process bitcalc
      bits(i) <= '0';
      for j in 0 to chocies-1 loop
        if i mod values(j) = 0 and distance(j) then
          bits(i) <= '1';
        end if;
      end loop;  -- j
    end process bitcalc;
  end generate;

end architecture behavioural;
```

This should produce nothing but a handful of or gates of varying width.